# Is it possible to hook in after options have been processed in a certain package or class?

Tags: macros, programming, hooks

In other words: Is it possible to scan the input stream of a .sty or .cls file (without using Perl) for `\ProcessOptions\relax` and nest some given code afterwords? (The filehook or etoolbox package dont provide such macros. Or am I missing something?)

And as a **Remark:** Is it ethically correct to use such a macro to patch a package or class? (When I thought about it, I came to the conclusion that it must be alright to do so in a world where `\renewcommand` does exist. But please let me know what you think about it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal way in TeX is not to scan ahead but simply to redefine the command.

```
\let\savedPO\ProcessOptions
\def\ProcessOptions{%
  \savedPO\relax
  \typeout{my stuff here}}
\usepackage{somepackage}
\let\ProcessOptions\savedPO
```

Probably outputs `my stuff here` just after the `somepackage` package has processed its options, then puts things back so later package loading is unaffected.

Redefining LaTex internals has risks, but it is certainly possible.